# A relation between sides in triangle $ABC$

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, triangles

If we have below relation in triangle $ABC$ what is $\hat{B}$
$$60\\120\\135\\150$$
the relation is $$a^2+c^2+3a^2c=(a+c)(ac+b^2)-3ac^2$$
I tried it many times ,but I get stuck ...may I use cosine theorem ?

Can someone give a ray of hope? please ... Thanks in advance.

Remark: It was given from one my colleague. I am in doubt with it, because if it was $$a^3+c^3+3a^2c=(a+c)(ac+b^2)-3ac^2$$ I can solve it easily, and $\hat{B}=120$ but in this case, I don't know what to do.

Comment: @MathLover: can you elaborate more please ? or make it clarify ?!

Comment: Is it written OK? Is it perhaps $a^3$ instead $a^2$?

Comment: $\angle B$ cannot be determined uniquely from the given relationship. For some values of $a$, $b$, and $c$, we can show that $\angle B = 120^\circ$. Check, for example, $a = c =1$, and $b=\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: I would expect $a^3$ and $c^3$ to make the equation homogeneous - it looks "dimensionally" wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the Law of cosines,
$$b^2=a^2+c^2-2ac\cos(\hat{B}).$$
Hence, by the relation it follows that
$$\frac{a^2+c^2+3a^2c-3ac^2}{(a+c)}-ac=b^2=a^2+c^2-2ac\cos(\hat{B})$$
which implies that
$$\cos(\hat{B})=\frac{(a+c)(a-c)^2-a^2-c^2}{2ac(a+c)}.$$
This means that $\cos(\hat{B})$ depends on the values of $a$ and $c$.

P.S. Note that with the relation $a^3+c^3+3a^2c=(a+c)(ac+b^2)-3ac^2$, following the same approach we get $\cos(\hat{B})=-1/2$, that is $B=120^{\circ}$.

Answer (score 0):

So we can rewrite the formula like this $$a^2+ac+c^2 =b^2$$
so we have
$$a^2+ac+c^2 =b^2 =a^2+c^2-2ac\cos \beta$$
and thus we get $$ \cos \beta =-{1\over 2}\Longrightarrow \beta = 120^{\circ}$$

Comment: :please tell me how i turn to $a^2+ac+c^2 =b^2$ ?

Comment: This is if you have $a^3$ and $c^3$.